# Pivot Chart Table in Excel To Calculate the Count and Display the Chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

Here is my Sample Data

```
            ****Date |  Name |  Result****

            01-09-14 |  John |  Fail

            01-09-14 |  John |  PASS

            01-09-14 |  Raja |  Pending

            01-09-14 |  Raja |  Pending

            01-09-14 |  Natraj |    No Response

            01-09-14 |  Natraj |    PASS

            02-09-14 |  John |  PASS

            02-09-14 |  John |  No Response

            02-09-14 |  Raja |  Fail

            02-09-14 |  Raja |  Pending

            02-09-14 |  Natraj |    No Response

            02-09-14 |  Natraj |    PASS

            02-09-14 |  Natraj |    Fail

            02-09-14 |  Natraj |    Fail
```

Where i need to create a pivot chart for table like this where i need to count the Number of Result for a particular date and for particular Name

**Example:**

the chart should produce result something like this

```
            Date| Name | Pass | Fail | Pending | No Response

            01-09-14| John | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0

            01-09-14| Raja | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0

            -------------------------------------------
```

Where i tried of adding an another sheet and table for counting seperately for pass, fail, pending... values and from there i created a pivot chart, but the actual table extends further

For example new user can add, new date will be added in future, as like that chart also have to be responsive of adding new user and new dates , so i failed in that point,

so is there any way to make the pivot chart to be responsive though new user or new date is added, the chart has to built automatically and to show the count result of particular date and particular name

Comment: Use a [**Table**](http://contextures.com/xlPivot01.html) as source data.

Comment: Thanks L42 now i got the data as per what i expected, butnow problem is if i add new row and if i refresh the table, it throws an error like , The pivot table field name is no0t valid. To create a new pivot table report, you must use data thats is organized as a list with labeled columns.  If you are changing the name of the pivot table field, you must type a new name for the field

Comment: Ok, so you have your data and made a table out of it. And your adding data right? Basically, the table should automatically resize when you add data at the bottom and the pivot table linked to it should automatically adjust data as well. Where are you adding your data?

Comment: Yes right L42, thats what i need

Comment: oh sorry , i am adding data in the actual table where i created the  table as source data, so if i add another row of data it should automatically add to the chart also

Comment: Then you shouldn't have any problem. That error usually occurs if your source data have no header. If your source is a table, it surely have a column header. It automatically creates one if you don't have it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60810/discussion-between-musthafa-and-l42).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: oh but my table is entirely different , how to do this , what is the procedure, i created list and i created a pivot table as per the source you mentioned but table didnt formed like this

Comment: It is on the link I provided. There is a link there that discusses about tables and how you'll create it. Just select your data and press insert table on your ribbon (if you're using 2007 and up)

Comment: yaa i done in the same way but table is not like this wait let me try one more time

Comment: here's the link on [how to create tables](http://contextures.com/xlExcelTable01.html). I guess that's all you need.

Comment: I have created a table as per the link u provided, then i clicked insert->pivot chart and table,table name was there correctly and also created in new worksheet, but the resulting chart is not exactly like yours, after creating a table what i have to do please help me

Comment: Thank you L42 I got it , i done a mistake in not moving the fields at right side, at drag fields, thats problem, now i got it very very thanks L42